# Невозможно восстановить БД postgresql на fedora 26

Tags: heroku, fedora, postgresql9.6

Необходимо восстановить базу данных на локальной машине. Дамп базы был сделан на heroku. При попытке восстановления БД с помощью `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump` получаю ошибку `pg_restore: [архиватор] неподдерживаемая версия (1.13) в заголовке файла`. В интернетах пишут, что надо обновить postgres, но для fedora работоспособной версии 9.6.8 нет. Подскажите как восстановить БД?

Comment: Ну если пойти путем апгрейда сервера, то попробуйте подключить репозитарий постгреса https://yum.postgresql.org и проапгрейдить постгрес.

Comment: я попытался установить этот rpm https://fedora.pkgs.org/26/fedora-updates-testing-x86_64/postgresql-libs-9.6.8-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm.html, но по каким-то причинам он наглухо удаляет пакет postgres-server, пробую ставить постгрес сервер и федора принудительно даунгрейдит постгрес до версии 9.6.7

Answer (score 2):

`dnf --enablerepo=updates-testing install postgresql-libs-9.6.8` решает данную проблему.